# Message boxes in chrome don't display properly in VMware

Tags: display, browser, vmware, vmware-player

I am using Windows 10 Professional inside VMware and some "message boxes" that pop up in browsers (chrome, edge, etc) do not display properly. I am calling them message boxes because I don't know the exact term for them. This is an example of what I meant

[image]

This is the box that pops up when I click the lion icon in Brave browser. This same problem happens in every other message pop-up of this type in all the browsers installed. Other than this the display looks normal for everything. Is this a graphics driver issue? How do I fix this?

VMware version: VMware® Workstation 16 Player, 16.2.3 build-19376536 running Windows 10 Pro, version 21H2, OS build 19044.1889

Host: Windows 10 Pro, 64-bit (Build 19044.2006) 10.0.19044, version 21H2

Comment: I have display issues with Edge (not Chrome) in a Windows 10 Pro guest inside VMware Workstation V16.2.4 running on a Windows 11 Pro host. I think it is a driver issue, but I have not nailed down which driver or found a solution.

Comment: @John in my case its in all the browsers, and only for this particular type of message box. Do you know what is the word for this message box object so i start googling something?

Comment: I am working on this. Chrome in the WIN 10 guest is fine. I do not know an alternate name for the message box.

Comment: Does disabling hardware acceleration in Chrome help at all? https://www.howtogeek.com/412738/how-to-turn-hardware-acceleration-on-and-off-in-chrome/

Comment: @jamesdlin no that didn't work but disabling "Accelerate 3D graphics" in Display settings of VM worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (temporary?) solution to this problem is to disable hardware acceleration in Chrome alone or to disable "Accelerate 3D graphics" as a whole in the Display settings of the VM.

EDIT: WMware finally released Workstation **version 17.0** on the 17th of november 2022 that fixes the problem! You also have to update VMware Tools inside the OS of course.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: disabling "Accelerate 3D graphics" as a whole in the Display settings of the VM was what worked for me